# Triangular function plot in gnuplot

Tags: c, gnuplot

I'm making the coordinates of triangular function in c code, and save them to a .dat file to plot in gnuplot. Here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 100
double tent(double x){
if(0<=x && x<=0.5){
        return 2*x;
}
if(0.5<x && x<=1){
        return 2*(1-x);
        }
}

int main(void){
int n;
double x[102];
x[0]=0.7;
for(n=0;n<=N;n++){
x[n+1] = tent(x[n]);
printf("%lf %lf\n",x[n],x[n+1]);
printf("%lf %lf\n",x[n+1],x[n+1]);
}
return 0;
}
```

When this code is executed, x coordinate data and y coordinate data are properly set in .dat file, but the data does not output as expected output.

This is part of the contents of the .dat file.

```
0.400000 0.800000
0.800000 0.400000
0.400000 0.799999
0.799999 0.400002
0.400002 0.800003
0.800003 0.399994
0.399994 0.799988
0.799988 0.400024
0.400024 0.800049
0.800049 0.399902
0.399902 0.799805
```

I don't know why, but it converges to 0 on the way. So, gnuplot doesn't plot triangular function. How can I fix this? Any advices would be appericiated.

Comment: Please edit question and add code/command-line that you use to plot the datafile. Seems perfectly legit to me

Comment: What is your actual problem? That the calculation is wrong? You are calculating the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map which for your case of mu=2 us chaotic. In this case the plotting with gnuplot is irrelevant. Or do you mean, that gnuplot plots the data wrong? Then it would be irrelevant how you generate the data, but the plot command and current output would be interesting... Please decide what applies

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

1. Why does it converge to 0?

One reason is the use of floating point calculations. [Here](https://floating-point-gui.de/) you can find more details. Another reason which explains the limit 0 instead of infinty or something else is the fix point behaviour of your equation. (I think, the second reason is quite interesting, but it is beyond the scope of this question and figuring out how it works will not help us in plotting a triangular function.)

2. Return value of the `tent` function.

Your `tent` function does not have a `return` if x < 0 or x > 1. Your compiler should give you a warning about that. (I compile with `gcc -Wall`.) You should add `return 0;`.

3. The usage of your function.

I understand your function `double tent(double x)` as follows: it takes a parameter `x` and calculates its corresponding `y` value. But when you call the function, you always take an `y` value as input to calculate another `y` value. Is this really what you want?

I think you might want to have an array of `x` values and then calculate the array of corresponding `y` values.

4. Why do you have two `print` statements?

It might be that I don`t understand your use case.

5. Why do you need the array?

You calculate a value and print it. No need for an array, or am I wrong?

6. Use the `N` everywhere.

Don't use `N` on some points and a hardcoded `102` on other points. And, avoid having both 100 and 102.

Until now, we arrive at the following C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 11 // instead of 101 just for debugging

double tent(double x){
   if(0<=x && x<=0.5){
      return 2*x;
   }
   if(0.5<x && x<=1){
      return 2*(1-x)
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(void){
   double x;
   double y;
   double x0 = 0.0;
   double x1 = 1.0;

   for(int n=0; n < N; n++) {
      x = x0 + n*(x1-x0)/(N-1);
      y = tent(x);
      printf("%lf %lf\n", x, y);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
0.000000 0.000000
0.100000 0.200000
0.200000 0.400000
0.300000 0.600000
0.400000 0.800000
0.500000 1.000000
0.600000 0.800000
0.700000 0.600000
0.800000 0.400000
0.900000 0.200000
1.000000 0.000000
```

You can plot this with `plot "a.dat" with lines`.

7. Do you need the c code at all?

You can plot a triangular function directly within gnuplot:

```
set xrange [-1:2]
set samples 1000
plot (abs(x-0.5) < 0.5) ? (1 - 2*abs(x-0.5)) : 0
```

The function definition is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) and adapted to your `tent` function.
This is the result:

[image: triangular function]

Again, it might be that I did not understand your use case.